# Powerview doubleclick custom link

Tags: sql-analysis-services

Is it possible to  have a custom link in PowerView on a SharePoint page?
For example, embedding JavaScript to open a custom dialog or anything else which would work..

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 Power View is Silverlight based so I am not aware of any way to add in a custom link.

In 2013 it is supposed to be moving to HTML5 so may offer more flexibility though I think it is still Silverlight at the moment.

Comment: yea - in SP2013 it's unfortunately still Silverlight based.